# Handling MMDDYYYY format in integer format python

Tags: python

Code asks user for date in MMDDYYYY format and works fine if they enter a date where both the month and year double digits (example: 11152003 = 2003/11/15) however. if I were to enter 522003 it should print 2003/02/05. I want some guidance that could help me solve this, not allowed to convert to string, or use if statements. Just % and division stuff.

```
userInput = int(input('Enter the date in the format MMDDYYYY: '))

year = userInput % 10000
userInput = int(userInput/10000)
day = userInput % 100
month = int(userInput/100)


print(f'The reformatted date: {year}/{month}/{day}')
```

Comment: I you enter 522003 it does not respect MMDDYYYY: shoudn't raise an error? or hint towards 05022003? In the same vein, what if you input 1112003: is it Jan 11 or nov 1st?

Comment: How are you going to decide if `xxx2003` is `0xxx2003` or `xx0x2003`?

Comment: @Demi-Lune I put in 522003 and it spit out 2003/0/52

Comment: I assume you are using Python3.  If so, you almost certainly want to use integer division (i.e., `//` not `/`).  That will eliminate the need to recast and ensure you always get the number you expect.

Comment: "not allowed to convert to string"- just sounds fishy. Anyway, just compare the number magnitude, as it will 100 times smaller than the number including the century information.

Comment: Make 3 list with year month and days. Then example if 20030618 then use year.append(userinput[0:3] like this so it will split and add into year list then yoi can print as u want. U can do like slice if know about it

Comment: @jsbueno Yea it is for a school assignment, just needed guidance hence I asked for tips and not just the fixed code lol. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't convert the string to an int. That is not an appropriate step in parsing a string as a date.

Answer (score 0):

522003 is an invalid entry according to your original criteria, It would be something more like 05022003 which would be received as an int as 5022003.

Furthermore, to resolve this issue where you have one missing number, you can always get the reminder of dividing by 1000000, in this specific case ending up with: 22003, then, you can easily find how to find the year/day. And I believe this should be enough to figure out the rest (use the reminder if you want one side of the date, or the division if you need the other side)